# Add Html Table Header Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am working in rails application.I need to show response in table format in UI through Java script.I want result like below table format

```
Device    5E:78:90:88            6E:88:99:13               98:90:20:38

Response  {"statusCode": 200}    {"statusCode": 200}     {"statusCode": 200}
```

Below the code i am  trying but not coming proper result.

HTML File

```
 <div class="col-md-6 span3 border-0 ">
<table  id="http_response"  class="table table-bordred table-striped">
 <thead>
     <td class="info">
   <tr><th>Device</th></tr>
   <tr><th>Response</th></tr>
 </td>
 </thead>
   </div>
```

JS

```
function display_result (result, mac) {
 var obj = JSON.parse(result['response'].body)
  var pretty = JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 4)

   td = $('<td>')
   td.append('<tr><th>' + mac + '</th></tr>')
   td.append('<tr><td>' + pretty + '</td></tr></td>')
   $('#http_response').append(td)

 }
```

Above Code Showing result as(Mac is not coming in heading)

```
Device

Response
{"statusCode": 200} {"statusCode": 200}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table is a bit messed. Table structure in html should be like:

```
table
  (thead/tbody optional)
    tr
      th/td
```

If you want your table to grow horizontally - you need to add `th`/`td` to existing rows:

```
<table id="http_response"  class="table table-bordred table-striped">
  <tr class="device_row"><th>Device</th></tr>
  <tr class="response_row"><th>Response</th></tr>
</table>
```

and js:

```
function display_result (result, mac) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(result['response'].body);
  var pretty = JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 4);

  $('#http_response tr.device_row').append('<th>' + mac + '</th>');
  $('#http_response tr.response_row').append('<td>' + pretty + '</td>');
}
```

Comment: One more query.How to remove table data.I am trying below $('#http_response tr').empty(). But it removing entire table.

Comment: @User1983 $('#http_response td:not(:first-child)').remove()

Comment: ok thanks.It is removing response results only.I want keep Device and response and delete mac and response results..

Comment: @User1983 try to figure out yourself how to make it also remove `th`

Comment: I tried this $('#http_response th:not(:first-child)').empty()

Comment: it is removing Mac but if i am giving $('#http_response tr:not(:first-child)').empty() which is actually removing entire response column.

Comment: @User1983 hint: it will be exactly the same as above, just th instead of td